# How to Overwrite the URL?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this URL:

> [http://qwertyuiopasdfghjklçzxcvbnm](http://qwertyuiopasdfghjkl%C3%A7zxcvbnm)

And I want to change it to something else without changing the page:

> http://www.something.com

Is this possible? If it is tell me the code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) or [replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) methods

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, "/your-new-url");
```

OR

```
window.history.replaceState(null, null, "/another-new-url");
```

Comment: is that javascript?? where i shoudl pu it???

Comment: yes, it's javascript, put it inside a `script` tag, i.e. `<script>here</script>`

Comment: yes but inside the head tag??

Comment: anywhere in the body

Comment: @MiguelMarques  de nada :)